# Optimization of a drone given a cost function

Tags: neural-networks, optimization

Currently, I have a drone that has 6 motors.  Each motor takes a different amount of power to run.  The objective of the drone is to travel at a constant desired velocity, with the minimum amount of electricity.

I built 2 models (linear and neural network) predicting the velocity as a function of the different currents to the motors.  I have another model to calculate for the total cost of the current strategy.  I am wondering what kind of optimization I can perform to find the optimal current for each of the motors.

Mathematically:

$Velocity = \alpha \times Motor_1 + \beta \times Motor_2 +... + \gamma \times Motor_6$

$Cost = 0.25 \times Motor_1 + 0.35 \times Motor_2 ... 1.3 \times Motor_6$

As seen from above, the cost to running different motors is different; some motors cost more, some cost less.  Which optimization algorithms can I use to find the optimal amount of current to send to each motor, while ensuring a given velocity is satisfied?

I know things like genetic algorithm would work, but is there any other better algorithms?

Comment: I think the term of art that you're looking for is "linear programming" because the problem as you've stated it is a linear program with inequality and equality constraints: you want to minimize cost  such that you provide a non-negative current to each of six motors and the velocity is constant. Is this interpretation correct?

Comment: And without further constraints you would put all the necessary current though the single best motor in terms of velocity to cost ratio

Comment: Thanks Sycorax and Henry for the replies!  Sycorax, yes, the interpretation is correct, however, I also have a neural network model to more accurately predict the velocity.  I imagine I would have to look up non-linear programming to optimize for that?  Henry, thanks for the input, you are absolutely correct.  I would definitely put constraints on each motor; lower = 0, higher = 70% of maximum.  Is there any additional constraints I should think about in optimization?  Thanks again.

Comment: What you've written is *exactly* linear, both in terms of velocity and cost. I'm not an aeronautics engineer, so I don't know whether a linear expression is correct. But if the equations you've written are what you want to optimize, then this isn't non-linear, it's linear. Are the coefficients in the expression for velocity unknown? -- If so, then you'll need to estimate them in some way. In terms of constraints, you need to include all relevant information. For example, if only 2 rotors are on, does the drone "tilt" on one axis or become unbalanced? Is that a problem? I don't know.

Comment: Hi Sycorax,  sorry for the confusing last comment.  The equation I posted in the question is indeed a linear equation.  And I assume I am able to optimize it in some way using linear programming.  However, I have a second non linear model that I did not post in the question.  The reason I showed the linear model first to ensure I am able to grasp the concepts of optimization and do it for a simple case.  Then, I wanted to optimize my non linear neural network model.  Because my 2nd model is non linear, I assumed that I need to learn non linear programming to optimize the non linear equation.